# Installing SSL Certificate Issued by CA on JBoss EAP 6.3

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, jboss6.x, keytool

I have a certificate generated by a CA. The CSR for this certificate was raised by my IT team using Microsoft IIS Server. I would like to install this certificate in my JBOSS EAP 6.3  server. Can some one please help me with the steps?